# URL Request parameters not detected in PHP for bingbot

Tags: php, apache, web-crawler

I have a bizarre thing happening, bingbot is spidering my website, and one such URL looks like this:

https://xxxxx/programme.php?action=view&id=2233

In my code, I have this function:

```
function getNumericValue($value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
            return mysql_escape_string($value);
    }
    if (isset($_GET[$value])) {
            if (!is_numeric($_GET[$value])) {
                    echo "$value must be numeric.";
                    exit;
            }
            return mysql_escape_string($_GET[$value]);
    } if (isset($_POST[$value])) {
            if (!is_numeric($_POST[$value])) {
                    echo "$value must be numeric.";
                    exit;
            }
            return mysql_escape_string($_POST[$value]);
    } else {
            echo "Please specify a $value";
            debug("Please specify a $value - " .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' : '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].' : '.print_r($_POST, true).' USERID: '.getUserid());
            exit;
    }
```

}

The debug() function emails me errors every 15 minutes, and when microsoft spider the site, I am getting: Please specify a id - /programme.php?action=view&id=2233 : msnbot-NewsBlogs/2.0b (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm) : Array ( ) USERID: -1

You can see from the URL that it has an id, but PHP is totally ignoring it.  It is fine for google spiders.

Any ideas what could be happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Just an FYI, instead of checking $_GET and $_POST, you can use $_REQUEST: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Also, I think you meant to use elseif.  Your code looks like it should, but it's actually not.  The last else is only for the `isset($_POST[$value])` part.

Lastly, what's the expected output you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks - I had used REQUEST until I found this weirdness, so have been trying all sorts!

Comment: Oops - enter submits, sorry.  I'd like BingBot to spider the URL above ) (blar.php?id=1, then getNumericValue('id') get the valueof $_GET['id'] - however, it is is not thinking it is set in the request parameters as it is hitting the ELSE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess - maybe there's an extra space after id number and is_numeric('2233 ') returns false. Try trimming the value taken from $_GET/$_POST (or $_REQUEST for that matter):

```
function getNumericValue($value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
            return mysql_escape_string($value);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST[$value])) {
            $request_value = trim($_REQUEST[$value]);
            if (!is_numeric($request_value)) {
                    echo "$value must be numeric.";
                    exit;
            }
            return mysql_escape_string($request_value);
    }

    echo "Please specify a $value";
    debug("Please specify a $value - " .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' : '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].' : '.print_r($_POST, true).' USERID: '.getUserid());
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It won't be that, as it is hitting the ELSE clause, i.e. PHP doesn't think the REQUEST parameter is being set!  But thanks for the suggestion.